# Counter Example to Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm attempting to answer the following question:

I'm trying to find two analytic functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ defined on some open and connected set $U$, such that the set $ \{z: f_1(z) = f_2(z)\}$ has an accumulation point but $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not equal on all of U. I know that this accumulation point must lie outside of U otherwise it contradicts the identity theorem.

I have a hint to try $\sin(z^{-1})$ so I've defined $f_1(z)=\sin(1/z)$ and $f_2(z)=\sin(-1/z)$, $U=\Re_{>0}$ and $Z_n=1/{n\pi}$. The sequence $Z_n$ tends to $0$ which is therefore an accumulation point of the set, lying outisde of the set. We also have that $f_1$ and $f_2$ do not coincide on $U$ however my $U$ is not open so I know this answer is wrong.

Can anyone give me some ideas on what else to try?

Comment: What is the natural domain of $\sin \frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: Just take the open right half plane, i.e. the set of $z\in\mathbb C$ with $\Re z>0$. I thought your notation $\Re_{>0}$ was meant to denote just that ....

Comment: Thanks, should have spotted that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is very good using the function one. I have an answer which is also defined with sine, on the unit disk $D(0,1)$ not including the boundary, such that $f(z)$ and the $0$ agrees on a sequence with accumulation point 1 which is not in $D(0,1)$. I don't want to spoil your fun.

Hint:
Consider this sequence
$$
1-1/n\pi
$$
which converges to $1$. (out of the open set given above)

Try to redefine your sine function.

Comment: That's great thanks